# Checking on a condition in loop

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a function that gets all elements by id, one-by-one and compares their id with their className.

If one of them is different, the element id'50' src e set for X, else (if they are all equal) the element's src e set to Y.

The thing is, if element id'50' == class'50', it sets src automatically to Y, even though some elements have different id and class.

It appears to be testing only the last element instead of testing all.

```
function checking(){
  for(var i = 1; i < 51; i++){
    if(document.getElementById(''+i+'').id != document.getElementById(''+i+'').className){
      document.getElementById('50').src = '../images/X.gif';
      complete = false;
    }
    else{
      document.getElementById('50').src = '../images/Y.jpg';
      complete = true;
    }   
  }
}
```

Only simple Javascript.

Any suggestion are welcome!

Comment: Don't use IDs that start with a number.

Comment: Also don't use CSS class names that start with a number. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors

Comment: Apart from that it's completely nonsensical to have elements that have the same class and ID. Don't do that.

Comment: IDs and classes can start with a number in HTML5. There is no such thing as "CSS class names". It's true that CSS identifiers can't start with a number, but it can be escaped.

Comment: @Oriol Of course there is such a thing as ["CSS class names"](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier).

Comment: @Tomalak CSS has no classes. It only has class selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the last one is tested (or that's how it seems) because you never stop the loop. So naturally, it continues till the end and `complete` is the last value set.

If you want to stop when setting it to `false`, then use `break` or even `return` since it seems you're done at that point.

---

And FYI, this is pretty pointless...

```
document.getElementById(''+i+'').id
```

It's the same as doing `i` or technically `i.toString()`.

---

So rewriting your code, we could do this instead:

```
function checking(){
  for(var i = 1; i < 51; i++){
    if(i != document.getElementById(i).className) {
       document.getElementById('50').src = '../images/X.gif';
       complete = false;
       return;
    }  
  }

  document.getElementById('50').src = '../images/Y.jpg';
  complete = true;
}
```

Here I got rid of the `else` and put its code down below the loop. Now if there's a non-match, we set `complete` and return. If no non-matches are found, it goes to the code after the loop when the loop is done.

---

It does however seem like you're abusing variables. We don't know where `complete` is, but it seems like you should just return the desired boolean.

```
function checking(){
  for(var i = 1; i < 51; i++){
    if(i != document.getElementById(i).className) {
       document.getElementById('50').src = '../images/X.gif';
       return false;
    }  
  }

  document.getElementById('50').src = '../images/Y.jpg';
  return true;
}

var complete = checking();
```

---

Or a cleaner approach would be to create a single selector for all the IDs and use `.every()`.

```
var sel = "#" + Array.apply(null, 50).map(function(_, i) { return i+1; }).join(",#");

var complete = [].every.call(document.querySelectorAll(sel), function(el) {
    return el.id === el.className;
});

document.getElementById('50').src = '../images/' + (complete ? 'Y.jpg' : 'X.jpg');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `src` attribute before entering the loop, and only change it if the `id` and `className` attributes don't match. You also need need to `break` or `return` once you've found a mismatch:

```
function checking() {
  var fifty = document.getElementById('50');
  fifty.src = '../images/Y.jpg';
  for (var i = 1; i < 51; i++) {
    var e = document.getElementById(i);
    if (e.id != e.className) {
      fifty.src = '../images/X.gif';
      return;
    }
  }
}
```